# Countable Product of discrete spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a countable discrete topological space. Consider $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ endowed with the product topology.

How do you prove that $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is homeomorphic to the sub-space of all irrational numbers?

Comment: Take $X = \mathbb{N}$ and use [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

Comment: Look for "Baire Space"

Comment: http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/continuedfractions.pdf

Comment: An alternativ proof can be found under theorem 1.1 at http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9401202v1.pdf